# How to pause background music in game using AVAudioPlayer for multiple scenes

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

So I have a background music looping in the background in my GameViewController. The pause music button is available in the GameScene where a user can mute or unmute the game music.

I have two global variables:

```
var muteButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pause")
var mute: Bool = false
```

Inside my GameScene I've added, things work like they are suppose to (the print responses are triggered).

```
class GameScene: SKScene{

    override func didMove(to view: SKView){
       ...
        muteButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.2, y: self.size.height*0.90)
        muteButton.name = "Mute Button"
        muteButton.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(muteButton)
    }

   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeITapped.name == "Mute Button"{
            if mute == false {
                print("music will now turn OFF")
                mute = true
            }
            else{
                print("music will now turn ON")
                mute = false
            }

         }
      }
   } 
}
```

I suspect the mute variable is only being called once in the GameViewController viewDidLoad, and thus the if statement is being checked only once. Since I have multiple senses connected that all need to have music playing, the best place for me to put the backgroundAudio would be here.
In my GameViewController:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController{

    var backgroundAudio = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Background Audio plays throughout the game
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Track1",ofType:"mp3")
        let audioNS_URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

        if mute == false{
            do{ backgroundAudio = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioNS_URL as URL)}
            catch { return print("No Audio Found")}
            // audio will loop forever
            backgroundAudio.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundAudio.play()
        }
        else{
            backgroundAudio.pause()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an observer inside `GameViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(switchBackgroundAudio), name: NSNotification.Name.init("switchBackgroundAudio"), object: nil)
    //... other stuff here ...//
}
```

then add a function for switching the sound on/off:

```
@objc func switchBackgroundAudio() {
   if mute == false {
     backgroundAudio.play()
   } else {
     backgroundAudio.pause()
   }
}
```

finally whenever inside your `GameScene` you touch the button, you may launch an event:

```
if nodeITapped.name == "Mute Button"{
  //... stuff here ...//
  NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: NSNotification.Name("switchBackgroundAudio")))
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm! My only problem is that the music doesn't play by default without the button being triggered. I can't figure out how to work around this

Comment: put a breakpoint inside `super.viewDidLoad` at this line`if mute == false{` what's happen?